# Finding coordinates with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

Let $B={{(1,x,x^2)}}$ and $C=(1,3x+4x^2,2x+3x^2)$ be bases for $P_2(\mathbb R)$.

Find the coordinates of $x$ and $x^2$ with respect to the basis $C$.

I'm a little stuck on where do begin for this question, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $C$ is a basis for $P_2(\mathbb{R})$, then you may write $x$ in terms of the vectors of basis $C$. This being said, there exist $c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$x = c_1 + c_2 (3x+4x^2) + c_3(2x+3x^2) = c_1 + (3c_2+2c_3)x + (4c_2 + 3c_3)x^2$$

Then solve

$$\begin{align}\begin{cases}c_1 &=0\\3c_2+2c_3 &= 1\\ 4c_2 + 3c_3 &=0\end{cases} \end{align}$$

to find $c_1,c_2,c_3$. Similar approach to $x^2$.

Comment: Ok so once I found $c_1,c_2,c_3$, this $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ would give me the coordinates of x? Then I do the same method

$$x^2=c_1+c_2(3x+4x^2)+c_3(2x+3x^2)$$

and once again solve for $c_1,c_2,c_3$ and again give me coordinates $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ for the $x^2$?


Also, does the basis B play any role in this question?

Comment: @user184692 That's correct! And it does, because in order to find $c_1,c_2,c_3$ you solve the system based on the representation of $x$ and $x^2$ in terms of the basis B. For example $x = 0 + 1x + 0x^2$.

Comment: Ok, so I used the above method, found $(0,3,4)$ in terms of $x$ (w/ respect to basis C) and found $(0,-2,3)$ in terms of $x^2$ (w/respect to basis C.  Although I finished solving the question, I never used any information from B to solve this question, or does B just explain C?

Comment: @user184692 Yes you did, you had to write $x = 0.1 + 1.x + 0.x^2$. This a linear combination of $x$ on the basis B.

Comment: So I just subconsciously used B, as it only creates a linear combination for $x$ and $x^2$? Other than that, I got it!

Comment: @user184692 You've used it directly. Without it you wouldn't have a linear system to solve.